# ADB Shell Commands Not Working in Android x86

Tags: adb, android-x86

In android X86 the shell commands sch as

```
adb shell input tap x y,

adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 0 5 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 3 1 29 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 1 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 330 0 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

are not working

and also while using input tap command  Android x86 Restarts.

Comment: define "not working" & `When using input tap x86 Restarts.`

Comment: when using input tap command Android x86 restarts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Works after turn off Developers Options.